# Defective eigenvalues problem - determining defect given a relation among elements, deducing third linearly independent eigenvector, etc.

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose I have the following matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 3 & 1 \\
        -2 & -4 & -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

The only eigenvalue of which is $\lambda = 1$ with a multiplicity of 3. Solving the expression $(A - \lambda I)$ yields eigenvector solutions of the form $a = -2b - c$. Where

$$ x = \begin{bmatrix}
        a\\
        b\\
        c\\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

We can easily find two linearly independent vectors of this form, such as

$$ x_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
        -2\\
        1\\
        0\\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$ x_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
        -1\\
        0\\
        1\\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

**My question: Is there any way we can pre-determine the defect of an eigenvalue given some kind of relation among the components of its associated eigenvectors (e.g. $a = -2b - c$)? Is the defect of the eigenvalue in this particular example 1? And how do I determine a *third* linearly independent eigenvector (I am looking for an intuitive answer here, as my book has a weird way of explaining things), and what conditions must that eigenvector satisfy?**

Comment: The eigenspace is only two-dimensional, so you’re not going to find a third linearly independent eigenvector.

Comment: Thank you! That answers my first and second questions!